# Get current/active security zone of a .NET application?

Tags: c#, .net, security, cas, security-zone

I have an application that behaves oddly, and just to verify, I'd like to see which security zone it is currently running under.

I've found the System.Security.SecurityZone enum, but can't seem to find anything that will return which of these I'm running under.

Does anyone have any tips?

Basically I want to find out if my application is running in MyComputer, Intranet, Internet, Untrusted, Trusted, etc.

---

**Edit:** Here's the minor test-app I wrote to find this code, thanks to [@blowdart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2525/blowdart).

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace zone_check
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(".NET version: " + Environment.Version);
            foreach (Object ev in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Evidence)
            {
                if (ev is System.Security.Policy.Zone)
                {
                    System.Security.Policy.Zone zone = (System.Security.Policy.Zone)ev;
                    Console.WriteLine("Security zone: " + zone.SecurityZone);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to look at the CAS evidence for the current assembly;

this.GetType().Assembly.Evidence

[Assembly.Evidence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.evidence.aspx) is a property [Evidence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.policy.evidence.aspx) object. From this you can [enumerate the evidence](http://www.improve.dk/blog/2008/06/11/analyzing-assembly-evidence) and look for the zone which appears as a <System.Security.Policy.Zone> element.

Comment: Niceness, thanks, I'll paste the final code here for future reference.

Comment: You're welcome. Of course in real life you wouldn't have to do this, you'd be making CAS demands and acting accordingly :)

Answer (score 3):

In .NET 3.5 you can simplify the code with LINQ:

```
Zone z = a.Evidence.OfType<Zone>().First();
```

From .NET 4.0 you have a convenient `GetHostEvidence` method:

```
Zone z = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Evidence.GetHostEvidence<Zone>();
```

Note that from .NET 4.0 evidence classes derive from the `EvidenceBase` base class.

HTH,
György

Answer (score -2):

You can also use

```
Evidence e = Thread.CurrentThread.GetType().Assembly.Evidence;
```

instead of

```
this.GetType().Assembly.Evidence
```

Comment: `Thread.CurrentThread.GetType()` returns the same `Type` instance as `typeof(Thread)`, so you're retrieving evidence for the `Thread` class's assembly (`mscorlib`), not the developer's assembly.

Comment: All I know is when I'm trying to do an xsl transformation in a shared class then this syntax works! Whereas the more commonly used this.GetType().Assembly.Evidence will not as in this case there is no instance. Major thanks - I would never have guessed that! :)