# Under which security zone is a ClickOnce application running?

Tags: wpf, security, clickonce

I have installed a [WPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation) application through [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce). By default it is installed under:

```
C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\...
```

Installing ClickOnce application from the Web or a network share will enable different security zones permissions as described in the MSDN article *[Securing ClickOnce Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76e4d2xw.aspx)*. The default permissions are based on the location from which the original version of the application was deployed.

Let's say the application is installed (on Windows 7, .NET4, but I do not know from where), how can I check under which security zone it is running on?

There is a similar Stack Overflow question, *[Get current/active security zone of a .NET application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239463)*, but it requires writing code. I want to check this through Windows capabilities on an already installed application.